# Prove limit of $\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\ldots+\frac1{n+n}$ exists and lies between $0$ and $1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

Prove limit of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+n}$ exists and lies between $0$ and $1$.

So far I have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}=L$ for some $L>0$.

Then given any $\epsilon >0,\exists N>0$ such that if $n>N$, then $\displaystyle\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}-L\right|<\epsilon$

A hint would be appreciated!

Comment: [Is $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/is-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-limits-n-k12k-frac1n-0) (and lots of other questions linked there)

Comment: The limit is $\ln2\approx0.7$, by the way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a monotone rising sequence: if $$s_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + ... + \frac{1}{2n},$$ then we have $$s_{n+1} - s_n = \frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2} > 0.$$

It is bounded below by $0$; and it's bounded above by $1$, because $$s_n = \frac{1}{n+1} + ... + \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{n} + ... + \frac{1}{n} = 1.$$ So it converges to a limit between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I like the use of the monotone convergence theorem here.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: It's a Riemann sum. ${}$${}$

Comment: Thank you, I did try Riemann sums, and got $$\displaystyle\lim\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+1}$$. I know Riemann sum to integral is of the form $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)\delta x_i=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$, where $\delta x_i=\frac{b-a}{n}$. In this case, would $f(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}+1}$?

Comment: ..."and got it right" ...or what?

Comment: @DonAntonio The suspense, it's killing me :)

Comment: sorry, whenever I hit "enter" it saved my comment...

Comment: @brenna, in fact $$\frac1{n+k}=\frac1n\frac1{1+\frac kn}\implies f(x)=\frac1{1+x}\ldots$$

Comment: Nice hint....+1

Comment: @brenna The integral is $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x+1}$.

Comment: @brenna I was joking btw when I said suspense. :)

Comment: @brenna $\large{\tt shift}$ $+$ $\large{\tt enter}$ goes to a new line without publishing your comment.

Comment: @PeterM haha yes i know : ) thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k\hphantom{\frac1{2k-1}+}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}-\frac1k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\frac1k\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and by the [Alternating Series Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), the series in $(1)$ converges.

Also by the Alternating Series Test, the limit is between any two consecutive partial sums; in particular, the first two are $0$ and $1$ (followed by $\frac12$, $\frac56$, and $\frac7{12}$).

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306747), that limit is shown, without calculus, to be $\log(2)$.

---

**Evaluating the Limit**

We will use the inequality
$$
e^x\ge1+x\tag{2}
$$
Substituting $x\mapsto-x$ in $(2)$ and taking reciprocals yields
$$
e^x\le\frac1{1-x}\tag{3}
$$
Applying $(2)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
e^{\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}}
&\ge\frac{n+2}{n+1}\frac{n+3}{n+2}\cdots\frac{2n+1}{2n}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\\[4 pt]
&=2-\frac1{n+1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(3)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
e^{\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}}
&\le\frac{n+1}n\frac{n+2}{n+1}\cdots\frac{2n}{2n-1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2n}n\\[9 pt]
&=2\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log\left(2-\frac1{n+1}\right)\le\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}\le\log(2)\tag{6}
$$
Thus, the limit is $\log(2)$.

Comment: Is the $H(2n)-H(n)$ a trick for series used in conjunction with alternating series test? I'm going to have to study the linked answer a bit.

Comment: @brenna: I think I've brought everything into this answer, so you shouldn't need to read the previous one now.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\xi_{k} \equiv k/n$ and $\Delta\xi \equiv \xi_{k + 1} - \xi_{k} = 1/n$

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k + n}
=
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n\xi_{k} + n}\,n\Delta\xi
\sim
\int_{1/n}^{1}{{\rm d}\xi \over \xi + 1}
=
\ln\left(2\right) - \ln\left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)
\to
\color{#ff0000}{\large\ln\left(2\right)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$

$f(n+1)-f(n)>0$

$\lim\limits _{n\to \infty} f(n)=\log2<1$

$f(2)=\frac{7}{12}>0$

Hence $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+,0<f(n)<1$

Answer (score 1):

The sum is increasing and bounded.$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+n}<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n} =1.$$