# How do i prove the Euler-Mascheroni constant is positive?

Tags: real-analysis, euler-mascheroni-constant

Define $\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k - ln(n)$.

I know that $\gamma$ is nonnegative, but i don't know how to prove that it is positive.

Comment: Each "term" $\frac{1}{k}-\ln k$ of the sum is positive.

Comment: @Andre How does that imply that $\gamma$ is positive? $\{1/n\}$ converges to 0 even though each term is positive

Comment: We have a sum of positive terms, so the sum is increasing.

Comment: @Andre $\{\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k - \log n\}$ is a decreasing sequence

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n/306379#306379

Comment: @John.p: Yes, I must have been thinking of $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{k}-log(n+1)$, same limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple comparison suffices:  consider the functions $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}, \quad g(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}.$$  Clearly, $g(x) \ge f(x)$ for all $x \ge 1$.  Integrating both on $[1, n]$ gives $$\int_{x=1}^n f(x) \, dx \le \int_{x=1}^n g(x) \, dx,$$ or $$\log n \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} < \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: I know that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log n >1/n$. But how does that gurantee that its limit is positive

Comment: Think about the picture:  Consider $$D_k = \int_{x=k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} - \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{k} - \log(k+1) + \log k > 0.$$  Then the limit of the partial sums of $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log (n+1)$ is simply $$S_\infty = \sum_{k=1}^\infty D_k > 0,$$ and your sum is even larger than that.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n/306379#306379