# $\ln{2n+1\over n+1}<{1\over n+1}+{1\over n+2}+\cdots +{1\over 2n}<\ln 2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Using the fact: ${x\over 1+x}<\ln (1+x)<x$, when $x>0$; deduce that:
\begin{equation}
\ln{2n+1\over n+1}<{1\over n+1}+{1\over n+2}+\cdots +{1\over 2n}<\ln 2
\end{equation}

This problem also asked to prove the fact I have given. I could prove it using MVT, but the deduction which should be easier is out of my hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof for $\log\frac{2n+1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}<\log 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/957977).

Answer (score 1):

Make a change of variables $y = \frac{x}{1+x}$, we have: $x = \frac{y}{1-y}$. So, from $\frac{x}{1+x}<\ln(x+1)$, we have :
$$y<\ln(\frac{1}{1-y}) = -\ln(1-y) \tag{1}$$

And because $\ln(1+x)<x\tag{2}$

From (1) and (2), we deduce that

$$\ln(1+x)<x<-\ln(1-x)$$

Replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{n+k}$ for $k=1,...,n$
$$\ln(n+k+1)-\ln(n+k) < \frac{1}{n+k}< -(\ln(n+k-1)-\ln(n+k)) $$
Hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln(n+k+1)-\ln(n+k))<\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}<\sum_{i=1}^n(\ln(n+k)-\ln(n+k-1))$$
or
$$\ln(2n+1)-\ln(n+1)<\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}<\ln(2n)-\ln(n)$$
or
$$\ln \left(\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \right)<\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}<\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

The fact is: $\frac{x}{1+x} \lt \ln(1+x) \lt x$, when $x > 0$. Since we particularly know that $\ln(1+x) \lt x$, we can write:
$$\begin{align} & \ln(2n+1)-\ln(2n)=\ln\Biggl(1+\frac{1}{2n}\Biggl)\lt\frac{1}{2n} \\
& \ln(2n)-\ln(2n-1)=\ln\Biggl(1+\frac{1}{2n-1}\Biggl) \lt \frac{1}{2n-1} \\
& \space \space \space \space \space \vdots \\
& \ln(n+2)-\ln(n+1)=\ln\Biggl(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\Biggl)\lt \frac{1}{n+1} \\ \end{align} $$ If we rewrite these expressions in a single line all at once, we eventually get: $$\ln\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\lt \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots +\frac{1}{2n}$$
$\ln()$ is an increasing function where it is defined. We can write for any $x>\frac{1}{2}$ that: $$\ln\Biggl(2-\frac{1}{x}\Biggl)\lt \ln2 \lt \ln\Biggl(2+\frac{1}{x} \Biggl)$$
Therefore, we can deduce that: $$\ln\frac{2n+1}{n+1}=\ln\Biggl(2-\frac{1}{n+1}\Biggl) \lt \ln2 \lt \ln\Biggl(2+\frac{1}{n+1} \Biggl)$$ Finally: $$\ln\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \lt \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} \lt \ln2$$