# Series of Harmonic sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$, then find all real numbers $p$ such that the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{H_n^p}$ is convergent.

My attempt is: There exist a subseqence of natural numbers $(n_k)$ such that $H_{n_k}>k$. Hence for $p>1$ we have sub series of the main series which is convergent.

But I can not conclude anything for the main series except $p<0$. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What does it matter that the series contains a convergent subsequence?  $\sum \frac 1n$ has many convergent subsequences, but it still diverges.

Comment: That "subseries" proves nothing: If $a_n$ is any sequence tending to zero there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $\sum_k a_{n_k}$ is convergent...

Comment: Have you tried using [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651009/showing-that-harmonic-numbers-are-theta-log-n-intuitively) that $H_n \sim \log n$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: You need to start with an estimate of approximately how large $H_n$ is.