# Doubt on limit of sum of sequences. Two procedures leads to different answers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

I have the following problem.

Determine the convergence or divergence of the sequence $(x_n)$ where $$x_n=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n}.$$

**My first approach was**:

Well, since $(x_n)$ is the sum of the sequences $\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right),\ldots,\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ and each of them are convergent, in fact they converges to $0$, then the limit of $(x_n)$ must be $0$.

**My second approach was**:

If we make the calculations, we have that $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}>0$$ then $$x_{n+1}>x_n$$ i.e., $x_n$ is an increasing sequence.

Also, as in $x_n$ we sum $n$ elements which are less or equan than $\frac{1}{n+1}$,  then $$x_n=\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2n}<\frac{n}{n+1}<1$$ i.e., $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence.

Now, since $(x_n)$ is increasing and bounded sequence, it follows that its limit is the supremum of $(x_n)$.

**Annoying question.**

But how $(x_n)$ can converge to $0$ (as shown in my first approach) and at the same time converges to its supremum when it is an increasing sequence? Can be 0 its supremum? It is not a contradiction?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first approach is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please tell me why?

Comment: The number of summands in $(x_n)$ increases with $n$.

Comment: Note that the sum is always $\ge 1/2$, so it cannot have limit $0$. In fact, it has limit $\ln 2$.

Comment: But why is the first approach wrong @AndréNicolas? I see that is wrong (because it leads to a contradiction) but I cant see exactly why. 
Also, if you can tell me how do you get that the limit is $ln2$ I would be very grateful.

Comment: The terms you are adding up indeed go to $0$. But as $n$ increases, you are adding together more and more of them.  As to a proof of $\ln 2$, two sketches of proofs are given in the answer. The question has been asked many times on MSE, a search should find solutions, though admittedly searching can be diffiicult.

Comment: Your first approach is like saying that $$0= 0+ \dots +0 = \lim_n (1/n) + \dots + (1/n) = \lim_n 1 = 1$$ where is the problem? Well, in the first equality the number of summands is not well defined (how many of them? $n$? and what is $n$?)

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550) and other posts which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/73550).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The limit of truncated sums of harmonic series, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73550/the-limit-of-truncated-sums-of-harmonic-series-lim-limits-k-to-infty-sum-n)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Proposed idea: Each of the terms converges to $0$; therefore their sum converges to $0$. [???]

That is true if the number of terms doesn't change as $n$ grows.  If $A_1,\ldots,A_{50}$ all approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$ then so does $A_1+\cdots+A_{50}$.  But if instead of $50$ terms, we have $n$ terms, so the number of terms grows as $n$ grows, then the conclusion is not longer valid.  For example consider this:
$$
\underbrace{ \frac 1 n + \cdots + \frac 1 n }_\text{$n$ terms}.
$$
This adds up to $1$, and that doesn't approach $0$ as $n$ grows, even though every term approaches $0$ as $n$ grows.

This sum can be viewed as a Riemann sum:
$$
\frac 1 n \left( f(1) + f\left(1+\frac 1 n\right) + f\left(1+\frac 2n\right) + \cdots + f\left( 1+ \frac n n \right) \right)
$$
where $f(x) = \dfrac 1 x$.  So this sum approaches $\displaystyle \int_1^2 \frac 1 x\,dx = \log_e 2$.

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: @WillSherwood : Thank you. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

You can use a well-known result in analytic number theory that $H_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3} +\cdots +\dfrac{1}{n} - \ln n$ converges to $\gamma$, and write $x_n$ in terms of $H_n$. Or you can use Riemann sum as a preferred method as follows: $x_n \to \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x}dx = \ln 2$

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Comment: also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n/306379#306379

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on only straightforward arithmetic and [Leibniz's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) for alternating series.

Proceeding with this way forward we first rewrite the series of interest $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$ as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{n-1}\frac1k} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, since $\frac1k$ converges monotonically to zero, Leibniz's Test guarantees that the series in $(1)$ converges.

> It might be interesting to note that while the series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges conditionally, the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty = \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}$ converges absolutely.  Therefore, we have two different convergent series representations, only one of which is absolutely convergent.

Note, we can evaluate the limit of series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ by recalling the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ is given by

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\tag 2$$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that the limit of the series of interest is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\log(2)}$$

which agrees with the results reported that used Riemann sums!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), you have $$x_n=H_{2 n}-H_n$$  For large values of $k$, the Wikipedia page gives $$H_k=\gamma +\log (k)+\frac{1}{2 k}-\frac{1}{12
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ which makes $$x_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

For illustration purposes, let us us $n=10$; the exact result is $\frac{155685007}{232792560}\approx 0.66877140$ while the above approximation would give $\log(2)-\frac{39}{1600}\approx 0.66877218$