# Proving that sequence is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking at the first answer to this question [Simple proof of showing the Harmonic number $H_n = \Theta (\log n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n), which claims that the following sequence is decreasing:
$$
f(n) = H_n - \log(n)
$$
where $\log$ is the natural log and $H_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i}$.

Here is my attempt to verify this:

Observe that 
$$
f(n + 1) - f(n) = H_{n + 1} - \log(n + 1) - (H_n - \log(n)) = \frac{1}{n + 1} + \log \left(\frac{n}{n + 1} \right).
$$
But this last term is positive, so it appears that the sequence is increasing! Where is my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Note that although $\frac{1}{n + 1}$ is positive, $\log \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ is negative as $\frac{n}{n+1} \lt 1$.

Comment: no, $n/(n+1)$ is smaller than one, so its logarithm is negative.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you. What would be a good way to show that this inequality is negative?

Comment: @Submarine I'm not sure what a particularly "good" way to show this inequality is negative, with it depending to a certain extent on what you have learned & know how to use. However, I would use a Taylor expansion of the natural log, in particular, the first one in [Taylor Series Expansions of Logarimathic Functions](http://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/logarithmic.cfm) and show the remaining terms are negative. However, this is something I'm not particularly expert at, so perhaps somebody here can give you a better suggestion.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for the comment. Do you know a good way to show that this inequality is negative?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} < \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t} = \log (n+1) - \log n \\ \implies \frac{1}{n+1} -\log (n+1) < - \log n$$

Answer (score 0):

As the other comments noted, although $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is positive, it is also less than 1 so its natural logarithm must be negative.
Thus, the problem comes down to showing that
$$\frac{1}{x} + ln\Big(\frac{x-1}{x}\Big)<0$$
That is equivalent to
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} - ln\Big(\frac{x}{x-1}\Big) < 0.$$
It's easy to see that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$
and also that
$$f^\prime (x) = \frac{1}{x^2(x-1)},$$
which is positive for all $x<1$. Thus, $f$ is a strictly inscreasing function. As such, $max(f(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Additionally, $f$ is not defined at $x=0$ so $f$ must be strictly negative.