# Finding $\lim{_{n \to \infty } } \frac{\frac{\sin(1)}{1}+\frac{\sin(2)}{2}+\frac{\sin(3)}{3}+...+\frac{\sin(n)}{n} }{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I tried to calculate this limit:

> $$\lim{_{n \to \infty  } } \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin(1)}{1}+\dfrac{\sin(2)}{2}+\dfrac{\sin(3)}{3}+...+\dfrac{\sin(n)}{n} }{n}$$

I've tried to compare to other term such as $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ or to use Dirichlet test but have no other ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You should know that this is the same as computing $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin n}{n}$$ thus the limit is $0$.

Comment: How come it's the same?

Comment: For a proof, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean

Comment: You can apply the Stolz theorem

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it

Comment: Or just applying old-good [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?

Comment: Maybe try to expres it as limit definition of definite integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(i)}{i}$ converge (by Abel's test) to some number $S$. Therefore, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(i)}{i} = 0$$

**Note:**

- You do not need to compute $S$.
- Another way to solve this problem is by applying Stolz lemma.
- A slightly harder version of this problem could be
  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{|\sin(i)|}{i} $$ 
  QC_QAOA has an answer for this.

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\lim{_{n \to \infty } } \frac{\frac{\sin(1)}{1}+\frac{\sin(2)}{2}+\frac{\sin(3)}{3}+...+\frac{\sin(n)}{n} }{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i)}{i}$$

But

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i)}{i}\right|\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|\sin(i)|}{i}\leq  \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=H_n$$

where $H_i$ is the $i$th Harmonic number. However, this is well known to be [bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n) by

$$H_n<1+\ln(n+1)$$

for large enough $n$. Thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i)}{i}\right|\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\ln(n+1)}{n}=0$$

Since the absolute value of the expression goes to zero, we conclude

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i)}{i}=0$$