# Estimate the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^ N \frac1n$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let $N\geqslant1$ be an integer. Then which of the following statements are true ?

1. $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac1n\leqslant1+\log N$
2. $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac1n<1+\log N$
3. $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac1n\leqslant\log N$
4. $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac1n\geqslant\log N$

**My Attempt :**
$$\underbrace{\frac11+\frac11+\frac11+\frac11+\frac11+\frac11+\ldots+\frac11}_{N\text{ times}}=N$$

$$\geqslant\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n=\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\ldots+\frac1N$$

$$\geqslant\underbrace{\frac1N+\frac1N+\frac1N+\frac1N+\frac1N+\frac1N+\ldots+\frac1N}_{N\text{ times}}$$

$$=\frac NN=1$$

$$\implies1\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n\leqslant N$$

Also $\;\log N\leqslant N,\;\forall N\geqslant1\,.\;$ I'm unable to combine this information to answer the question. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: $\log x = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t} \, dt$. Try computing lower and upper sums for this integral.

Comment: Hint is very nice but I don't know how to compute lower and upper sums of this integral.

Comment: Play around with [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bh7xtbknun) graph. For instance, $\log 2=\int_{1}^{2}\log t \, dt$. What's a simple way of coming up with an upper and lower bound for $\log 2$?

Comment: Please provide link of calculating lower and upper sums of the integral.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: As a simple extension/illustration of the answer of @Joe, consider that Joe's answer featured short rectangles.  Consider the same graph, only with tall rectangles.  Using this approach, it is easy to see (for example) that $(1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4) + (1/5)< \log(5) < 1 + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4).$

Comment: Duplicate of [Simple proof of showing the Harmonic number $H_n = \Theta (\log n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n) see the answer by Chris Jones, for example.

Answer (score 5):

$$\log(1+x)<x\;,\;\;\text{ if }x>0$$
Let $\;x=\dfrac1n\;,\;$ then
$$\frac1n>\log(1+n)-\log n$$
Next, by telescopic summing we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n>\log(1+N)-\log 1=\log(1+N)>\log N$$

**Edit :**

Let $\;f(x)=\log(1+x)-x$

$$\implies f'(x)=\frac1{1+x}-1=-\frac{x}{1+x}<0\;,\;\;\text{ if }x>0\;.$$

So $f(x)$ being a decreasing function of $\;x\;$ for $\;x\geqslant0\;,$

$$f(x)<f(0)\implies\log(1+x)<x \;,\;\;\text{ if }x>0\;.$$

Comment: This answer shows that option 4 is correct and option 3 is false. What about options 1 and 2 ?

Comment: The option 1 is true. The option 2 is false for $N=1$. You can prove that the option 1 is true by using Joe’s hint which is $$\log x=\int_1^x\frac1t\,dt$$

Comment: @Mera bhai Option 1 is correct. see my recent answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\log x = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t} \, dt$, meaning that the question invites a geometric solution. Below is a plot of $y=\frac{1}{t}$. By comparing the red areas with the area under the curve, convince yourself that $\frac{1}{2} \leq \int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{t} \, dt$, and $\frac{1}{3}\leq \int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{t} \, dt$, etc. What can you infer from this?

[image: Lower sums]

Comment: On summing above inequities, we get $\sum_{n = 1}^N\frac{1}{n} \leq \int_{1}^{N}\frac{1}{t} \, dt = log N$ which contradict above answers.

Comment: @Merabhai: That's not true. Note that the sum of the red areas is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{N}$, i.e. the sum starts at $\frac{1}{2}$, not $1$.

Comment: If the sum starts at $\frac{1}{2}$ then Is inequalities revert ?

Comment: @Merabhai: I don't understand what you mean. What my answer shows is that $\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\leq\log N$. Add $1$ to both sides...

Comment: It means options 1,2 are also correct. But Angelo said that  option 2 is false.

Comment: @Merabhai: The above diagram assumes that $N\geq 2$ (there's a limit to how useful any geometric aid can be). The case $N=1$ has to be dealt with separately. Just plug in $N=1$ and see which answer is correct.

Comment: @Merabhai, I just said that the option 2 is false for $N=1$, not for $N\geqslant2$, indeed the option 2 is true for any $N\geqslant2$.