# Sum of alternating harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Edit: As @FamousBlueRaincoat pointed out below, this question was based on an error in a wikipedia article.

The Wikipedia article on the harmonic series gives the following "proof without words" that the alternating harmonic series $1-1/2 +1/3 -1/4 + \cdots $ converges to $\log (2) $:
\begin{equation}
(1/1)(1/1 - 1/2) + (1/2)(2/3 -2/4) + (1/4)(4/5 - 4/6 + 4/7 - 4/8) + \cdots
= \log (2).
\end{equation}

Can anyone explain why the sum on the left is $\log (2) $? I don't see it right now.

Edit: my goal is specifically to understand this "proof without words" that the alternating harmonic series converges to $\log(2)$.

Comment: Why write $(1/1)(1/1 - 1/2) + (1/2)(2/3 -2/4) + (1/4)(4/5 - 4/6 + 4/7 - 4/8)$ instead of $1-1/2 +1/3 -1/4 + ...$? They are equal quantities and I don't yet see an advantage to writing it the former way..

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42718/48606).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \cdots $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716/sum-of-the-alternating-harmonic-series-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1k)

Comment: @LarryFreeman That answer does not explain the proof quoted above.

Comment: The answer to your question is that Wikipedia article should be edited. The quoted manipulation does not demonstrate anything on its own. By following the link [to the source](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Hudleson-MMz-201007804.pdf) you will see a geometric argument in which areas of certain rectangles correspond to the terms listed above. But without the picture, the series written in your post is just a pointless perturbation of the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

For $|x|<1$,

$$\frac 1{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$$

Integrate both sides to get
$$\log(1+x)=C+\sum_{n=0}{(-1)^nx^{n+1}\over n+1}$$

It's not hard to see that $C=0$, and reindexing gives

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^{n-1}x^n\over n}$$

Now, (waving of hands) let $x\to 1$ on both sides to get the result.

Comment: Thank you, I'm specifically trying to understand the "proof without words" though. (I believe Abel's theorem takes care of the hand-waving part of the argument you gave.)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, you're right about Abel's theorem.