# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am confused on whether this leads to a finite value or not, but it seems the value of the series alternates around a certain interval, making it seem convergent. Please give me a valid proof as to if it's divergent or convergent.

Comment: Have you heard of the Alternating Series Test?

Comment: No, please tell me.

Comment: The $N$-th partial sum is a Riemann sum for the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}$$ and since $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ is a continuous (hence integrable) function over $[0,1]$, your series is conditionally convergent to $$\log(2) = 0.6931471805599453\ldots $$

Comment: See also: [Sum of the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \cdots $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716). (Maybe also [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/716).)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n&=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots\\&=\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+\dots\\&>\frac12+0+0+0+\dots\\&=\frac12\\1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots&=1+\left(-\frac12+\frac13\right)+\left(-\frac14+\frac15\right)+\dots\\&<1+0+0+0+\dots\\&=1\end{align}$$

Lastly, note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=0$, and that

$$\frac12<S_{2n}<S_{2n+1}<1,\quad S_{2n}-S_{2n+1}\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty$$

where $S_n$ is the $n$th partial sum.

Thus, it is convergent and

$$\frac12<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n<1$$

---

The exact value can be found from the Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nx^n$$

Plugging in $x=1$ yields $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=\ln(2)$

Comment: @Nafi04 You are asking for the value of the series?  It is $\ln(2)$, due to the Taylor expansion of $\ln(x)$.

Comment: How about the actual value?

Comment: Nice squeeze, thanks

Comment: @cool.coolcoolcool ?  Your welcome?

Comment: Looks good now (+1). I'll remove my earlier comments to reduce clutter.

Comment: @Bungo Fist bump?  And happy holidays then.

Comment: @SimpleArt Same to you! I'm heading home now to enjoy some eggnog :-)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges using [Leibniz's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternating series test.
So consider the series:
$\sum a_n$

if $a_n$ is: 1)decreasing, 2)positive 3)converges to $0$

Then by the Alternating Series Test, $\sum (-1)^n a_n $ converges

In your case $a_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ which satisfies the above conditions, then the series you originally had converges by the alternating series test.