# How is $1- \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}...$ till infinity $= 2\log_e2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, euler-mascheroni-constant

How is  $1- \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}...$ till infinity $= \log_e2$? I know that $e^x = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}...$ but how is this result gotten? I don't have a very extensive knowledge of Euler's number, I just need to learn how to do this because it is part of the solution of a question I'm doing for self-study. Would someone please give me a simple explanation?

Comment: This question has answers here which I hope aren't too complicated [Sum of the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \cdots $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716/sum-of-the-alternating-harmonic-series-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1k)

Comment: also you can take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) or search in google for "mercator series" for some more extensive bibliography

Answer (score 4):

It comes from the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$:
$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n.$$
This is valid for $-1<x\le1$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution uses the Euler formula of complex numbers:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{in\pi}}{n}$ where $i^2=-1$

Expand the fraction by $i\pi$ and realize the following:

$-i\pi\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{in\pi}}{i\pi n}=-i\pi\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  e^{in\pi x} dx_{x=1}=-i\pi\int \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{in\pi x} dx _{x=1}$

Sum the geometic series we get:

$-i\pi\int \dfrac{e^{i\pi x}}{1-e^{i\pi x}}dx$ using the $t=e^{i\pi x}$ substitution and $t=-1$ at $x=1:$

$-\int \frac{1}{1-t}dt= - \big(-ln(1-t)\big)_{t=-1}=ln2$