# Prove a series $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence

I was asked to prove that an infinite series
$$\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ is a convergent series.

I tried using ratio test but the limit results in 1 which is inconclusive.

I am stuck at this point.

Can you give me some hint on how to approach this question?

Thank you

edit : My professor only taught ratio test, root test and comparison test where if $|b_i| \leq a_i$ for all i = 1, 2, ... and $\sum a_i$ converges then the sum of $b_i$ converges absolutely. Is there any way other than alternating series test to prove this problem?

Comment: Hint: Alternating series

Comment: Use Leibniz test

Comment: Or, use the fact $\frac 1n\to0$ and group the term, use the comparison test.

Comment: And [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716/sum-of-the-alternating-harmonic-series-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1k) similar question.

Comment: @J.G. What a pity you deleted your answer! I think it was the most appropriate, requiring few knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Refer to [alternating series test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: My professor only taught ratio test, root test and comparison test where if |$b_i$| $\leq$ $a_i$ for all i = 1, 2, ... and $\sum a_i$ converges then the sum of $b_i$ converges absolutely. Is there any way other than alternating series test to prove this problem?