# if the sequence=$a_1, a_2, a_3$ has no limit, does that mean that the sequence $a_1 +\frac{a_2}{2} + \frac{a_3}{3}$ also doesn't have a limit?

Tags: calculus

I concluded that it also doesnt have a limit. I used IZREK 1 (o primerjanju). $I∞k=1 ak = a1 +a2 +... and ∞k=1 bk = b1 +b2 +...,$ where this is true for every $k —> 0≤ak ≤bk$
If the bigger function converges that means that the smaller function also diverges?

bk is the first sequence, and ak the second sequence.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

The conclusion does not hold. The sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$ has no limit, but $b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{k}$ has a limit because the series
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}
$$
converges due to the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). (And the value of this series [happens to be $-\ln 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716/42969).)

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. We may take
$$\{a_1\}=\{1,2,3,4\dots\}\\
\{a_2\}=\{2,4,6,8\dots\}\\
\{a_3\}=\{-6,-12,-18,-24\dots\}$$
None of these sequences has a (finite) limit, but $\{a_1+a_2/2+a_3/3\}$ is zero at every term, and thus has a limit of $0$.

Comment: but what if we take a_1=1 a_2=2 ....

Comment: @sasaako Each of $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ is a separate sequence. Your question - and the question body - make no sense.

Comment: doesnt that make the function without a limit? because a_1=1 a_2=1 ...

Comment: @sasaako See my previous comment.