# Find sum of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)}$, $f(n)$ - the number of ones in the binary representation of the number $n$.

Tags: calculus, summation

Here is task:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)}$$

Where $f(n)$ - the number of ones in the binary representation of the number n.

I tried separate $a_n$ to $\frac{f(n)}{n} - \frac{f(n)}{n+1}$ then we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)} = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{f(n) - f(n - 1)}{n}
$$
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}1&n=1\\f(z)& n = 2z\\f(z) + 1&n = 2z + 1\end{cases}
$$

Then we have, if n is odd in second sum:
$$
f(2z + 1) - f(2z)= f(z) + 1 - f(z) = 1
$$

Can't understand what I should to do next.

Comment: I believe it equals $\ln(4)$.
See https://oeis.org/A000120

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$ f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}\{\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \text{ is odd}\}, $$

where $\mathbf{1}\{\ldots\}$ stands for the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). Plugging this into OP's sum and interchanging the order of summation (which is allowed by Fubini–Tonelli Theorem),

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)}
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}\{\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \text{ is odd}\} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \mathbf{1}\{\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \text{ is odd}\}.
\end{align*}

Now we focus on the inner sum that runs over $n = 1, 2, \ldots$. Since the indicator function factor survives with value $1$ precisely when $\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor$ is an odd number, we may represent those $n$ by the form

$$ n = (2q-1)2^k + r, $$

where $q = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ and $r = 0, 1, \ldots, 2^k - 1$. So,

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \mathbf{1}\{\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \text{ is odd}\} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \mathbf{1}\{\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \text{ is odd}\} \\
&= \sum_{q=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r=0}^{2^k - 1} \left( \frac{1}{(2q-1)2^k + r} - \frac{1}{(2q-1)2^k + r + 1} \right) \\
&= \sum_{q=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{(2q-1)2^k} - \frac{1}{(2q-1)2^k + 2^k} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{q=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2q-1} - \frac{1}{2q} \right).
\end{align*}

In the third step, we utilized the fact that the inner sum is telescoping. However, the last sum is the famous [alternating harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716), which converges to $\log 2$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\log 2}{2^k}
= 2 \log 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can't understand this rows $$\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \mathbf{1}\{\lfloor n / 2^k \rfloor \text{ is odd}\} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{q=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{(2q-1)2^k} - \frac{1}{(2q)2^k} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\log 2}{2^k} \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @replikeit, Group the inner sum according to the value of $q = \lfloor n/2^k\rfloor = 1,3,5,7,\ldots$, and see how the sum over each group simplifies :)

Comment: Okay, but where log came from???

Comment: @replikeit, Check the [alternating harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716/9340): $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\cdots=\log 2. $$

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Comment: I tried to group but have not success it, didn't understand why $2^k$ is here, I think I missed something. Sorry for questions, this is the most hardest sum for me, before I have not experience with tasks like this. Could you answer this step more openly?

Comment: @replikeit, No worries. I added more details.

Comment: Thank you, you are my saver!!!!!

Comment: We getting $n$ only when this $n\mod{(2^k)}$ is odd. Then we have $n = (2q - 1)2^k + r$, where $r = 0, 1, 2, 3 \dots, 2^k - 1$. But if we get $n_0 = (2q - 1)2^k + 0.$ We have that, $n_0\mod{2^k}=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144449/discussion-between-replikeit-and-sangchul-lee).

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. This is not elegantly like answer before, but more simply.

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)} &= \frac12 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(2n)}{2n(2n+1)} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \\
&= \frac12 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{2n(2n+1)} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)+1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \\
&= \frac12 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \left[ \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \right] + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \\
&= \frac12 + \frac12 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}.
\end{align*}
Then we have
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)} &= 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} = 1 + 2\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = 2 \left. \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n} \right|_{x=1} = 2\ln (1+x) |_{x=1} = 2\ln 2.
\end{align*}